# Always mount DVD as /media/MEI_UDF

Tags: mount, dvd

I have several DVD_ROMs which I use for backup and archival purposes and I *think* they were all formatted with the same command. I have not had to add anything to `/etc/fstab` for them to be recognized: I simply insert the disc and Ubuntu ( 14.04 but I've seen it on previous versions ) mounts them automatically.

I use scripts which use the DVD mount point ( yes, I can pass in the name if necessary ).

Sometimes, the discs mount as `/media/MEI_UDF` and I can use them without root privileges to copy onto, delete and so forth.  Other times they mount as ( something like ) `/media/b64df485faa34534552989c34c53e4f5df536dfcf` and I need to use sudo to copy, delete etc.  I'd like to be able to use the former for all the discs. I can reformat them if need be.

Any ideas, for example what the difference is between discs?